# Evaluating real integrals through residues

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Say we are trying to evaluate a real integral of the form
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx$$
through the use of residues. Typically, the contour used is a closed semi-circle formed by the segment that goes from $(-R,0)$ to $(R,0)$ and $C_R: |z|=R$. For this question, we can assume that $f(z)$ has a finite number of singularities inside the contour, then, the approach would be to evaluate 
$$\int_{-R}^Rf(x)\,dx=2\pi i \sum_{k=0}^n\text{Res}(f,z_k)-\int_{C_R}f(z)\,dz$$
and then show that the integral on the right of the equality approaches zero through the Darboux inequality (then of course take the real part and so on). However, my question is, if we know that the initial (real) integral converges, do we have to show that such integral approaches zero? In other words, is it enough to write it as $$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(x)\,dx=\Re\left[2\pi i \sum_{k=0}^n\text{Res}(f,z_k)\right]$$

Comment: If the integral over $C_R$ does *not* got to $0$, then your conclusion isn't true.  If the integral approaches some limit $L$, then you have to take $L$ into account in your calculations.

Comment: @saulspatz But sometimes, even in that case we can use Jordan’s Lemma to arrive at the desired result. Basically, what I am trying to ask, is that, if we proved that the original integral is convergent, can we use the last equation in my question? Without needing to check if the integral over $C_R$ approaches zero. In other words, does the fact that the initial integral converges imply that the integral over $C_R$ is $0$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As an example, consider 
$$
I = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{\cos x}{x^2+1}\,dx
$$
and choose $f(z) = \dfrac{\cos z}{z^2+1}$ (normally you would take $f(z) = \frac{e^{iz}}{z^2+1}$ to compute $I$ via residues). Cleary the integral converges and you can check that $I = \dfrac{\pi}{e}$, but
$$
2\pi i\operatorname{Res}_{z=i} \frac{\cos z}{z^2+1} = \pi\cosh 1.
$$

Comment: Thank you for the counter example!